# How to uninstall bookworm when I installed it from source?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, compiling, git

I am a new Linux user and i can't uninstall bookworm. I installed it using the steps recommended [here](https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm) to install from source:

> Run the command below to install the above on Ubuntu and Debian distros:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install unzip poppler-utils unar html2text python2.7 libgtk-3-dev libgee-0.8-dev libgranite-dev libsqlite3-dev libxml2-dev webkit2gtk-4.0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libpoppler-glib-dev meson valac gettext curl ninja-build appstream git
> ```
>
> Run `git clone` to download the source code, `meson build` to configure the build environment and run `ninja test` to build.
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm.git
> cd bookworm
> meson build --prefix=/usr
> mkdir -p build && cd build
> ninja
> ```
>
> To install, use `ninja install`, then execute with `com.github.babluboy.bookworm`.
>
> ```
> sudo ninja install
> com.github.babluboy.bookworm
> ```

I know that it was stupid of me to install from source when I'm a new user of Linux, but I thought that it could be uninstalled with `sudo apt-get --purge remove bookworm` or that maybe if that didn't work, the official GitHub or page of BOOKWORM would have a solution to do it, but I didn't find anything.

I would like to revert all the modifications done through the commands from the recommendation, because I don't know whether it will affect me in the future and I don't have any backups. Also, I don't trust Ninja and the other programs and libraries I installed while following the commands.

Comment: How you uninstall software depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. You must work backwards, first figuring out how to use ninja (NOT apt) to uninstall bookworm. Then you must figure out how to remove ninja. Finally, removing the stuff installed with apt is super-easy...but it must be done last. Don't skip steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you installed the application manually using `ninja`, there's no way to uninstall it without knowing exactly which files were created/touched by Ninja. In addition, since you used `--prefix=/usr`, all files have been installed directly to `/usr`, rather than `/usr/local`, which makes it even harder to revert because the application has now been installed side-by-side with the system files from your Ubuntu distribution.

Some applications may provide an `uninstall` target (or similar) for Ninja. You can use:

```
ninja -t targets
```

(in the same directory that you ran Ninja from when installing the application) to see the targets that your application provides. If there is an `uninstall` target, you may remove it by running

```
sudo ninja uninstall
```

Otherwise, there is no easy way to uninstall the application. The only way would be to manually investigate which files were created/touched by Ninja and remove them manually, but that would be tedious and hard work, especially for someone new to Linux.

This is why you should preferably always install applications using the package manager. If that's not possible, at least install them to `/usr/local` (which is typically the default) rather than directly to `/usr` as you did.

**Edit:** That being said, there's no reason to be overly worried. There's no reason not to trust the libraries you installed using `apt` (any less than any other library in your system installed via `apt`, which is essentially every single library), nor to not trust `ninja` itself (it's just a tool that can run a bunch of commands to build and install an application). As far as `bookworm` itself is concerned or the Ninja build files it comes with, I can't be sure. However, seeing as this application has close to 1000 stars on GitHub and 68 forks, it would be rather surprising if it had any intentional backdoors. Of course, that doesn't mean it can be deemed completely secure and without vulnerabilities, but that's true for just about any application.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply. It's really great to see that what i read and heard about Linux community being so supportive and friendly was true . I also found a [script](https://gist.github.com/TingPing/9c5903521ba856644e7b49ff8504ff0f) to delete all files and directories which could not be deleted by ' sudo ninja uninstall' or ' sudo ninja clean'.

Comment: @tomukomatsu You are very welcome. Note that the script you linked to has a comment that says it only works until Meson 0.38. If you have Ubuntu 19.10, you probably have Meson 0.51, so in that case it may not be useful to you. Also, all this script does is to simply delete all the files listed in `meson-logs/install-log.txt` (relative to the build directory). Having such an install log is of course a very useful thing: It tells you which files have been created/touched when you installed the application, thus enabling you to revert the installation.